# Using docker and hosts file

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm trying to get an hbase container running, and the container requires some *stuff* which means the docker host need to be available as "docker". We achieve this with setting the docker ip in the hosts file with docker. However, when I run:

`docker ps`

it tells me that the certificate is for localhost and not docker. The following works:

`docker --tlsverify=false ps`

My questions are:
* Is it possible to "update" something so that docker ps works?
* Is it possible to turn off tls verification through some environment variable?

I tried setting DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY to 0, and that didn't work. I know turning off tls is insecure, but this is for dev, and other automated scripts expect to run without specifying --tlsverify=false.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider (for testing) to generate a certificate for docker *and* localhost (adding the latter in [`SubjectAltName`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName))

[Adding localhost to Subject Alternative Name can have drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21197331/6309), but in your case, it would allow `docker ps` to run properly anywhere.

Comment: That sounds promising. Is there some way to feed that into docker-machine create?